# adding in SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, collections, sorteddictionary

I want to add table name as string and table value as arraylist if table name exist in same key add record as array list ...here showing key already exist . where i can modify :

```
SortedDictionary<string, ArrayList> DealInfo = new SortedDictionary<string, ArrayList>();
ArrayList Deal = new ArrayList();
string DealName=string.Empty;
foreach (DataTable table in RecentAddedDeal.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        if (!DealInfo.ContainsKey(Convert.ToString(dr["DealTab"])))
        {
            DealName = Convert.ToString(dr["DealTab"]);

        }
        Deal.Add(dr);
        DealInfo.Add(DealName, Deal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you still use an `ArrayList` and not a `List<DataRow>`?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want since your description says you want to use the TableName as the key, but your code is adding a column from the row as a key.

Going with the idea that the TableName should be the key, something like this should work:

```
var dealInfo = new SortedDictionary<string, List<DataRow>>();

foreach (DataTable table in RecentAddedDeal.Tables)
{
    if (!dealInfo.ContainsKey(table.TableName))
    {
        dealInfo.Add(table.TableName, table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList());
    }
}
```

Going with the idea that you want to key off a column in each row for the key, you could do something like:

```
var dealInfo = new SortedDictionary<string, List<DataRow>>();

foreach (DataTable table in RecentAddedDeal.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        var dealName = row["DealTab"].ToString();

        if (dealInfo.ContainsKey(dealName))
        {
            dealInfo[dealName].Add(row);
        }
        else
        {
            dealInfo.Add(dealName, new List<DataRow> {row});
        }
    }
}
```

To fill a ListView with data from a row for a specific DealName, you can find the dictionary entry for that deal name and access the list of rows this way:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dealInfo["SomeDealName"])
{
    // Here you have access to the rows where row["DealTab"] == "SomeDealName"
    // You can fill a list view with some column value from the row like:
    listView1.Add(row["SomeColumnName"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: table value is like this 
A  fullrow
B  fullrow
C fullrow
A fullrow 
if same key coming again then add in same key.arraylist

Comment: means one key- multiple row

Comment: if A as key coming again should be add in same arraylist but now giving error key already exist ...

Comment: @KrantiSingh Ok, I added another sample where the key is the value of the 'DealTab' column in each row, and if it exists then the row is added. Not sure why you want an arraylist...I'm using a List<DataRow>. You're welcome to modify it!

Comment: can you tell me how to fill different listview from this SortedDictionary means I have 4 row I want to fill 4 different listview

Comment: @KrantiSingh Cool. Feel free to mark as the answer if this is working for you. :)  I added a sample to show how to access the rows in the dictionary. It's similar to how they were added - you can get access to a list of rows for a dealName by specifying the dealName as the key to the dictionary, i.e: `dealInfo["SomeDealName"]` will contain the list of rows where `row["DealTab"] == "SomeDealName"`

Comment: foreach (string dealTab in dealInfo.Keys)
                    {
                        foreach (List<DataRow> deal in dealInfo.Values)
                    {
                        
                        rep1.DataSource = deal;
                        rep1.DataBind();
                        
                    } 
                }

Comment: both foreach working fine ....I need row header for access value in list view like <%#Eval("id") %> .....in list coming index[0]-4

Comment: @KrantiSingh Cool, glad it's working. If you still have different questions, you should post them separately from this one if this one is answered.

Comment: for voting ...saying required 15 reputation ...so I am not able to mark/vote your answer

Comment: No worries. You can come back later when you have more rep! ;)